# Как в git удалить папки только из удалённого репозитория?

Tags: git

Я добавил проект в удалённый репозиторий, потом написал в .gitignore игнорировать папку `.vs/`
Но на сервере эта папка присутствует.
Как мне обновить данные с учётом .gitignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Удалить папку из `.gitignore`
2. Удалить/переместить за пределы репозитория папку `.vs`
3. Закоммитить и запушить удаление этой папки
4. Добавить её обратно в `.gitignore`
5. Переместить папку обратно на свое место/запустить Visual Studio,
   чтобы её создало заново